# How do you setup MvxSuspensionManager

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross

There is a requirement for the UWP app that I'm creating to intercept the Suspending event and via an OnSuspending event handler write to a log file.

I understand that MVVMCross uses its own SuspensionManager, MvxSuspensionManager. I've searched [www.mvvmcross.com](http://www.mvvmcross.com) for MvxSuspensionManager documentation but can't find any. I've searched generally and found some information but it relates to version 5 and does not go into any detail. I did discover there's a reported bug that I too have experienced (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3772) that has been fixed but not yet pushed to master.

1. I'd like to know how to implement the MvxSuspensionManager to meet the requirement.
2. Is there any sample code or documentation showing how to set it up?
3. When will a new MVVMCross version be released containing the bug fix (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/3821)?

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Following the rules of the site, I would advice you to include a code you have tried into the question else your question will end flagged and removed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. At this point though I don't unfortunately have any code to include as I require documentation or code samples detailing how to implement MvxSuspensionManager before I can write any meaningful code.

Answer (score 0):

On your `MvxWindowsSetup` you can override `CreateSuspensionManager` and create your own. You only  have to inherit from `MvxSuspensionManager` (or implement `IMvxSuspensionManager`) in your class and override the methods you need like `SaveAsync`. So you can just fix the issue by overriding `SaveAsync` and doing the same than in the PR (furthermore you can add your custom behaviour there as well if you need it):

```cs
public class MyCustomMvxSuspensionManager : MvxSuspensionManager
{
    try
    {
        // Save the navigation state for all registered frames
        foreach (var weakFrameReference in _registeredFrames)
        {
            IMvxWindowsFrame frame;
            if (weakFrameReference.TryGetTarget(out frame))
            {
                SaveFrameNavigationState(frame);
            }
        }

        // Serialize the session state synchronously to avoid asynchronous access to shared
        // state
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), KnownTypes);
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, SessionState);

            // Get an output stream for the SessionState file and write the state asynchronously
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(SessionStateFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await fileStream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new MvxSuspensionManagerException(e);
    }
}

--------

public class MySetup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
    ...

    protected override IMvxSuspensionManager CreateSuspensionManager()
    {
         return new MyCustomMvxSuspensionManager();
    }
    ...
}
```

Also as you can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/32ad8e63458e00c5b284e52120519da9ce0f2399/MvvmCross/Platforms/Uap/Core/MvxWindowsSetup.cs#L67), by default it initiailizes the `MvxSuspensionManager` with the root frame of your application, you can change this as well overriding `InitializeSuspensionManager` on  your setup, or if you want to register another frame to manage its session then you can just resolve the `IMvxSuspensionManager` wherever you are in the app and call the register with your custom session state key: `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxSuspensionManager>().RegisterFrame(_myFrame, _suspensionManagerMySessionStateKey)`.

Finally I strongly suggest you read the [MvxSuspensionManager implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4cf2f37911b36aaef956b5b1dad0d7d07d131965/MvvmCross/Platforms/Uap/Views/Suspension/MvxSuspensionManager.cs) so you can understand what happens under the hood.

HIH